# Finding all byte positions where two files differ

Tags: c, comparison

With the following code, I'm able to compare two files and find the start position where they differ but now want to find all the places where they differ and print them out, not just the first place. I know it's a loop but I can't figure out how to do the loop. I thought with leaving the while loop as is and taking the break statement out it would work but it does not.
How I call it:

```
            if ((fp1 != NULL) && (fp2 != NULL)){
                compare_two_binary_files(fp1, fp2);
                }
```

How it's implemented:

```
void compare(FILE *f1, FILE *f2)
{
    char ch1, ch2;
    int flag = 0;

while (((ch1 = fgetc(f1)) != EOF) &&((ch2 = fgetc(f2)) != EOF)){
    if (ch1 == ch2)
    {
        flag = 1;
        continue;
    }
    /*
     * If not equal then returns the byte position
     */
    else
    {
        fseek(f1, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        flag = 0;
        printf("Byte pos where two files differ is %d\n", ftell(f1)+1);
    break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why is the flag variable there ?? what output are you getting when you remove the break and trying ??

Comment: The `break` ends your while loop. Remove it. You don't need the `continue` statement either. Using `fseek(-1)` and `ftell()+1` seems like unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
int count = 0;
while (((ch1 = fgetc(f1)) != EOF) &&((ch2 = fgetc(f2)) != EOF)){
    if (ch1 != ch2)
    {
        printf("Byte pos where two files differ is %d\n", count);
    }
    count++;
}
```